# How do I run Python script from Spyder with input arguments?

Tags: python, spyder

I want to write and test scripts for Kattis problems in Spyder. In Kattis problems a file with the test inputs are feed to the script. Like `python myscript.py < test.txt`.

I want to run my script in Spyder feeding the test inputs. How do I do that?

I used to be able to run a script in Spyder and specify command line arguments. Now, the only way this can be done is if the script is run in an external console. This console then closes as soon as the script finishes, so you can't see the output of your script.

I used to be able to set command line options in the General settings. (Like explained here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/7292)  But that seems not to be possible anymore.

I also tried `runfile('myscript.py', args = '< test.txt')` But the `args = '< test.txt'` seems to be ignored.

Opening a file in the script is not an option. The test cases **must** be read from stdin in Kattis problems.

How do I pass command line arguments / feed a text file to stdin?

Edit: Tried `Ctrl + F6` setting command line arguments in box. `'< test.txt'` The file gets ignored. Script waits for input in console.

Tried `runfile('myscript.py', args = '< test.txt')` Result: The file gets ignored.

I am using Spyder 5.5.0

Comment: Off the top of my head, try `Ctrl + F6`.  This (should) open a window in which you can enter CLI args to be run.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes, it’s `Ctrl + F6` —> General Settings —> Command line options.  Fill in the text field with the CLI args.

Comment: When I do that the console says "Runfile('....../b.py', args='< test.txt', wdir='...../Pyhon/kattis')"  This is fine. **But nothing happens** The script is still waiting for input rather than getting it from  the file.

Comment: Please share the script code, preferably for a basic Kattis problem so it can be executed and the behavior reproduced (it's probably something like `print(input())`, and the file might just be `hello world`, but this helps people unfamiliar with Kattis understand the code you're trying to run). If you're just trying to see the output in a console, open the console before running it so it's persistent.

Comment: Yes, `print(input())`, and the file could be hello world.

What Kattis problem is not important. The point is I am forced to read from stdin. I cannot open a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally have a solution that works:

Run configuration per file with the filename i.e. test.txt. Notice no ‘<’

Code will now read a file if args provides a filename else from stdin

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('filename', nargs='?', default=None)
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.filename is not None:
    f = open(args.filename)
else:
    f = sys.stdin

for line in f:
    print(line)
```